# React script not including dependent module source map if size of dependent module exceeds 244kb

Tags: reactjs, webpack, source-maps

I have react project (create using create-react-app) called "ui-web" and it has dependency on "ui-core". When bundle size of "ui-core" was less than 244kb, final build of "ui-web" was including source map of "ui-core". If size of "ui-core" bundle exceeds 244kb, react project stops including source map of "ui-core". Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If a node modules which is added as dependency, exceeds 244kb in size (minified JS file size), React script does not include source map for that module. If size is below 244kb, it is includes in final main js file.